# IOS How to merge one image on camera preview layer?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to add a png image (blue rect) on camera preview view layer. I get the preview image from this function:

```
-(void) captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection
{
    UIImage * image1 = [self ImageFromSampleBuffer:sampleBuffer];
    NSData *imageData1;
}
```

And this function is that set preview image to an UIImageview.

```
-(void) SetPreview
{
    
    
    session =[[AVCaptureSession alloc]init];
    session.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto;
    
    //Add device;
    AVCaptureDevice*device = nil;
    device = [self cameraWithPosition:AVCaptureDevicePositionFront];
    
    AVCaptureDeviceInput*input = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:device error:nil];
    
    if(!input)
    {
        NSLog(@"NO Input");
    }
    
    [session addInput:input];
    
    //Output
    
    output = [[AVCaptureVideoDataOutput alloc] init];
    [session addOutput:output];
    output.videoSettings = @{(NSString*)kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey:@(kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA)};
    
    //Preview layer
    AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *previewLayer = [[AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer alloc] initWithSession:session];
    
    cameraView = self.view;
    
    previewLayer.frame =CGRectMake(cameraView.bounds.origin.x+5, cameraView.bounds.origin.y+5, cameraView.bounds.size.width - 10, cameraView.bounds.size.height-10);
    
    previewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill;
 
   
    [_vImage.layer addSublayer:previewLayer];
    timer =[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(snapshot) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    
    [session startRunning];
    
    
}
```

How can I implement this feature?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

I solved this problem putting "Back Img" on the View.